# Tomcat HttpThread Pool Exception Handling in case of uncaught exception

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I would like to know how Tomcat container Http Thread Pool handles uncaught exception. 
In case of Java Thread Pool if tasks are submitted via execute() then in event of exception the Thread is terminated and replaced by a new Thread while in case of submit() the uncaught exception is handled and the Thread does not terminates.

So what happens when an http request server by a http thread in Tomcat throws an exception. Is http Thread terminated and replaced by a new one?
or
Is exception is handled and http Thread does not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8.5/9.0 handle this through subclasses of the `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase<S>` class. Grab the Tomcat [source code](http://tomcat.apache.org/svn.html) and have a look at what the `doRun` methods in those subclasses do.